# Counterpart of Ajax on server side

Tags: ajax, server

I am a beginner in web and server side development and have just read about Ajax. It is used on client side to access any resource over the internet.

But I am thinking of some utility on the server side as ajax so that server is able to send request to the client and client responds to the request.

Do you people know how to achieve this? Basically what I want to achieve is that I have a server which sends the curent server time to the connected client each second.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Do you want to the ajax request to get the server response?

Comment: Suppose you've accessed a website and have the page opened in your browser. I want the server to send the time to the browser and have it shown to the user wach second

Comment: I actually want opposite of that, " send something from server to each connected client and dynamically modify the page to show what has cone from user".

Comment: So you want to send from a server to the client

Comment: Yupp. To each client that has opened the webpage from that server each second

Comment: I would just recommend that you will send an ajax request without data in an interval and just always receive answers. Would that work?

Comment: That would work, but it is inefficient. It has double time. First request time and then response time.

Comment: It's really fast. If you insist I'd suggest using socket.IO or WebSocket. https://socket.io/docs/. If you still want to use ajax I can post an answer. Because using WebSockets/socket.IO is completely different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with websockets.

In .NET we use SignalR to achieve what you need. Server sends a message and client replies to it. This is pubsub scenario.

https://hackernoon.com/create-your-own-pubsub-client-server-use-websocket-65dd1820e997

Comment: I think socket.io is the best solution to my problem. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes use websocket but it works in browsers with HTML5 support.